# AS3 / AIR 3.5 Replace only part of a string

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, flash-cs5

AS3 | Flash CS6 | Adobe Air 3.5

I have a very long string that will eventually be formatted as XML.  In the string I have several instances of something along the lines of:

```
<title>Some title</title>

//the following line would need changed
<title>Some title</garbage>

<title>Some title2</title>
<title>Some title3</title>

//the following line would need changed
<title>Someone's title & (his info)</garbage>

//the following line should NOT change
<another title>something else</garbage>
```

I need to search and replace all of these:

```
<title>(whatever is here)</garbage>
```

And make them:

```
<title>(whatever is here)</title>
```

As you can see I can't simply search and replace "garbage" beacuse it wouldn't apply in every single instance... I only want to replace the ones that use < title > ...not < another title >  Also please note that it is uncertain what characters will be between < title > and < /garbage >

So although I know this doesn't work... I was thinking something along the lines of:

```
str = str.replace(/<title>\w+<\/garbage>/, "<title>\w+<\/title>");
```

I think the answer is under "Capturing sub-strings" on this page but so far no luck:
http://www.sevenson.com.au/actionscript/testing-regular-expressions/

It seems like at this point I'm just plugging in random things so it makes more sense to just ask for help.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Match any symbol after `<title>` and before `</garbage>`

```
str = str.replace(/(<title>.[^<]+)<\/garbage>/, "$1</title>");
```

Example http://regexr.com?33nog

Comment: I found one problem with this.  If the (whatever is here) is only one character long, this expression does not work.  Any suggestion on how to fix this?  For 2 or more characters it's great.

Comment: Edit:  Making it non-greedy fixed it.

/(<title>.[^<]+)<\/garbage>/, "$1</title>"

Becomes

/(<title>.?[^<]+)<\/garbage>/, "$1</title>"